# Unable to resolve symbol 'TapTargetView'

Tags: java, android, taptargetview

I am trying to implement the `TapTargetView` library from https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView

I have included this dependency in my **build.gradle (Module:app)**

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.11.0'
}
```

But upon implementing the code, I keep getting this error

> Unable to resolve symbol TapTargetView

Why is that? I've tried using these other dependencies too:

```
implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.12.0'
implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.13.0'
```

I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There was a mismatch in the version, the following implementation works for now:

```
implementation 'com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview:taptargetview:1.13.3'
```